# Google Chrome extension change devtools panel content

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome extension that adds a panel to the devtools. In this example I want to log every network request. The problem is that I don't know how to change panel html content. 
I tried to access `document` and `window.document` but without any success.

mainfest.json:

```
{
"name":"sesionID extractor",

"description":"Extract sessionID",

"minimum_chrome_version": "10.0",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,

"devtools_page": "html/devtools.html",

"permissions": [    
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

devtools.html just includes main.js

main.js:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("My Panel",
    "MyPanelIcon.png",
    "../html/Panel.html",
    function(panel) {

        chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
          function(request) {

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var text = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(request));
            div.appendChild(text);
            document.body.appendChild(div);

      });

    }
);
```

How to access Panel page content?

Answer (score 2):

As quick workaround I did following to access Panel window.

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("sessionID",
    "MyPanelIcon.png",
    "../html/Panel.html",
    function(extensionPanel) {

        var show = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            extensionPanel.onShown.addListener(function(panelWindow) {                            
                resolve(panelWindow);
            });                
        });

        show.then(function(_panelWindow) {
          // manipulate Panel's DOM content through _panelWindow            
        });

    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Panel.html` runs with the same privileges as `devtools.html`.

You can simply listen to the event within it and modify the page directly.

---

If you specifically need to access the panel's frame from the main devtools page, you can use `onShown` event of the panel, as [described in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#panel-window). This would allow, among other things, communication using `postMessage`.

As a alternative solution, you can use [Chrome Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging); however, because of the broadcast nature of messaging, having several instances of Dev Tools open will complicate things.